# Using kbhit() and getch() on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, getch, conio, kbhit

On Windows, I have the following code to look for input without interrupting the loop:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            if (_getch() == 'g')
            {
                std::cout << "You pressed G" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        Sleep(500);
        std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, seeing that there is no `conio.h`, whats the simplest way of achieving this very same thing on Linux?

Comment: The [*ncurses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library should help.

Comment: I've never actually done this, becasue doing this on linux is harder than what you had for windows.  I will leave [a link to an NCURSES howto on doing this with ncurses.h though.](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/scanw.html#GETCHCLASS)

Comment: ncurses worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ncurses howto cited above can be helpful.  Here is an example illustrating how ncurses could be used like the conio example:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int
main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    while (true) {
        if (getch() == 'g') {
            printw("You pressed G\n");
        }
        napms(500);
        printw("Running\n");
    }
}
```

Note that with ncurses, the `iostream` header is not used.  That is because mixing stdio with ncurses can have unexpected results.

ncurses, by the way, defines `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  A correctly configured ncurses will use the same data-type for ncurses' `bool` as the C++ compiler used for configuring ncurses.

Comment: afaik you should add an `endwin()` at the end of the program

Comment: only needed if the program exits -- it does not, in OP's question.

Comment: It does not.  It loops forever.

Comment: ohh... sorry ;) but dont you have to reset the terminal?

Comment: not in this case: one could exit with a *`^C`*, and ncurses would reset as described in [endwin](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers).

Answer (score 18):

If your linux has no `conio.h` that supports `kbhit()` you can  look [here for Morgan Mattews's code](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/_kbhit_for_Linux.shtml) to provide `kbhit()`  functionality in a way compatible with any POSIX compliant system.

As the trick desactivate buffering at termios level,  it should also solve the `getchar()` issue as demonstrated [here](http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html).

Comment: The getch is probably more important to @Boxiom.

Comment: This answer solved my issue, so thanks Christophe. But I would like to add that "#include <sys/ioctl.h>" was required for me to get Morgan McGuire's function to work in my program due to the use of FIONREAD, and that isn't explicitly listed as necessary on the web page where his code is found.

Comment: stropts.h no such file or directory. apparently linux doesn't support this anymore

Comment: @elig indeed, there seem to be some recent changes on the linux world: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=954552 - There are already some recent answers about similar issues with stropts.h on SO: maybe you find one suitable, maybe you open a new one. It would be great to add a comment if you find a solution for those who might experience the same issue with the same distro.

Answer (score 9):

A compact solution based on Christophe's answer is

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>

bool kbhit()
{
    termios term;
    tcgetattr(0, &term);

    termios term2 = term;
    term2.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term2);

    int byteswaiting;
    ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &byteswaiting);

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);

    return byteswaiting > 0;
}
```

Unlike that answer, this won't leave the terminal in a weird state after the program has exited. However, it still leaves the characters sitting in the input buffer, so the key that was pressed will unwelcomely appear on the next prompt line.

A different solution which fixes this problem is

```
void enable_raw_mode()
{
    termios term;
    tcgetattr(0, &term);
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO); // Disable echo as well
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);
}

void disable_raw_mode()
{
    termios term;
    tcgetattr(0, &term);
    term.c_lflag |= ICANON | ECHO;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);
}

bool kbhit()
{
    int byteswaiting;
    ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &byteswaiting);
    return byteswaiting > 0;
}
```

Usage is as follows

```
enable_raw_mode();
// ...
if (kbhit()) ...
// ...
disable_raw_mode();
tcflush(0, TCIFLUSH); // Clear stdin to prevent characters appearing on prompt
```

Now any characters typed between execution of the first and last lines won't show up in the terminal. However, if you exit with Ctrl+C the terminal *is* left in a weird state. (Sigh)

Comment: This works for determining if a key was pressed, but provides no way of getting the corresponding character (if you use getc(), you're still left waiting for the user to press Enter).  See this solution if you want to wait for a key to be pressed and immediately get the character: https://stackoverflow.com/a/912796/544099

Answer (score 3):

While using ncurses is functionally equivalent to the Turbo C "conio.h" API, a more complete solution is to use a conio implementation, as can be [found here](http://www.sandroid.org/TurboC/#Download).

You download and use it in your program for a very complete implementation of the conio interface, on Linux. (Or OSX.) Written by Ron Burkey.

Comment: A note on the Turbo C page states that mixing stream-based functionality with conio probably won't work.  That eliminates the principal reason one might want to use it, since the OP's example is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux, I found this solution where you can create your own local library:

http://linux-sxs.org/programming/kbhit.html

kbhit.cpp

```cpp
#include "kbhit.h"
#include <unistd.h> // read()
    
keyboard::keyboard(){
    tcgetattr(0,&initial_settings);
    new_settings = initial_settings;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    peek_character=-1;
}
    
keyboard::~keyboard(){
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &initial_settings);
}
    
int keyboard::kbhit(){
    unsigned char ch;
    int nread;
    if (peek_character != -1) return 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    nread = read(0,&ch,1);
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);

    if (nread == 1){
        peek_character = ch;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
    
int keyboard::getch(){
    char ch;

    if (peek_character != -1){
        ch = peek_character;
        peek_character = -1;
    }
    else read(0,&ch,1);
    return ch;
}
```

kbhit.h

```cpp
#ifndef KBHIT_H
#define KBHIT_H
    
#include <termios.h>
    
class keyboard{
    public:
        keyboard();
        ~keyboard();
        int kbhit();
        int getch();

    private:
        struct termios initial_settings, new_settings;
        int peek_character;
};
    
#endif
```

inside main.cpp I created an instance:

```cpp
#include "kbhit.h"

int main(){
    int key_nr;
    char key;
    keyboard keyb;
    while(true){
        if( keyb.kbhit() ){
            key_nr = keyb.getch(); //return int
            key = key_nr; // get ascii char
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```