# How to collect keyboard input inside a loop in c++

Tags: c++, linux

I have a program running a numerical calculations with precision increasing in time. It does so for different values of some parameters. The precision I need for each results depends on the value of these parameters, in a way totally unknown to me.

To get enough precision for each value, I am thinking about a program/loop that would cut a calculation and move on to new values of the parameters if the user hits the keyboard.

Schematically:

```
//initialise parameters
while( parameters_in_good_range){
     while( no_key_pressed){
         //do calculation
     }
     //update parameters
}
```

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: There's no way to poll the keyboard in standard C++, you need to rely on OS specific functions.

Comment: @MarkRansom not totally agree with you: since c++11, you can create thread and have some control on it, and have some basic synchronization mechanism. So you can have a thread which do calculation and a second one which read standard input. When second receive an input, it can tell to the other that it has to quit

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Linux

Comment: @Garf365 but *standard input* is different from *keyboard input*.

Comment: @close-voter: it's perfectly clear what this question is asking.  It says `while(no_key_pressed){/*do calculation*/}`.

Comment: @user2079303: right, I misread the comment about "keyboard input", I apologize. But you can poll standard input with modern c++ in a portable way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, this program will loop until a keyboard key is pressed :

```
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

On linux, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335758/using-kbhit-and-getch-on-linux). It tells you how to use ncurses to do what you want.

Comment: Why not `while(!_kbhit()) {/*do stuff*/}` ?

Comment: it doesn't really matter either way since OP is on Linux and not Windows

Comment: Link to a linux answer added above.

Comment: @V.Semeria a link isn't good enough, it isn't an answer unless it actually contains the relevant information.

Comment: It contains an example of ncurses that solves the question.