# Loop condition using getch() does not end the loop as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, abort, control-flow

I have following code, but it is not ending the `while` loop even if `done` is true. It keeps waiting for `_getch()`:

```
   while (done || ((c = _getch()) != EOF))
   {
       cout << "Operation aborted" << endl;
       break;
   }
   cout << "Operation finished" << endl;
```

**Edit:** In fact i want to be able to interrupt a long operation performed in another thread.  I believe I have to join thread after `while` loop. But with the following code, the loop is not getting executed when I press a key.

```
thread t(Start, folder_path);
while (done || ((c = _getch()) != EOF))
{
    cout << "Operation aborted" << endl;
    exit_signal.set_value();
    break;
}
t1.join();
cout << "Operation finished" << endl;
```

How can I end the loop when `done` is true ?

Comment: `while (!done...`?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Where is done changed ?  Is it multithreading code ?

Comment: done  is bool and set to "TRUE" by thread once thread is completed

Comment: I hope `done` is atomic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop conditions is written in a way that:

- if `done` is true,  the logical expression is short circuited and the **loop body is entered** without evaluating the right side of the condition.
- if `done` is false, then `_getch()` is called.  If there is a char returned, the expression will be true, and the **loop body is entered**.  If there's no char available, `_getch()` will wait until the user types one.  Only if the end-of-file is encountered (i.e. Ctrl+Z is entered in terminal mode, or cin is redirected from a file and its end is reached), will the loop be interrupted.

If you wanted a non-blocking keyboard entry,  you'd have to use [`_kbhit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=vs-2017) first, to check if a char is available, and then only read the char with `_getch()`. For `kbhit()` on linux, you may have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29335796/3723423).

**Edit: your multithreading edit**

First of all, if `done` is a variable that is used in both threads (which apparently it is, since it's not changed in the loop), make sure that it it declared **`atomic`**. If this is not the case, you'd have a race condition that is UB.

Now, your narrative doesn't match the code.  If `done` is when the other thread has finished, and you want to end the loop at this moment,  you'd need to loop on `!done`.

Furthermore,  if you want to loop as long as the other thread is running, but check the keyboard and let the user interrupt the code, you'd better do that check in the loop. By the way, it could be an option to go [`sleep_for`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/) a couple of milliseconds in the loop body, in order to avoid wasting to much CPU for querying the keyboard.

So the code would end up with a structure like

```
std::atomic<bool> done(false); 
...
thread t(Start, folder_path);
while (!done)
{   
    if (_kbhit() && ((c = _getch()) != EOF) { // if keystroke available
        cout << "Operation aborted" << endl;
        exit_signal.set_value();  // assuming this would make t1 return from folder_path()
        break;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    // update status bar or do other stuff 
}
t1.join();
cout << "Operation finished" << endl;
```

Finally, I don't know what `exit_signal.set_value();` is doing.  I hope it does do something that tells the other thread to stop the processing.  If it doesn't, your loop would finish, but at the `join()` you'd anyway have to wait for the other thread to complete.

Comment: HI Christophe,   Thanks. Any idea about the same api for Linux env ?

Comment: I believe I have to join thread after while loop. Following is the code. But Loop is not getting executed when I press key.
 thread t(Start, folder_path);
 while (done || ((c = _getch()) != EOF))
   {
       cout << "Operation aborted" << endl;
    exit_signal.set_value();
       break;
   }
    t1.join();
   cout << "Operation finished" << endl;

Comment: @user1833852 for kbhit on linux, you may look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29335796/3723423

Comment: @user1833852 ok, I've seen your edit and updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks Christophe for your help.