# Why don't online C++ IDEs support "graphics.h" header file?

Tags: c++, header-files, bgi

I tried compiling code using several IDEs of C++ using "graphics.h" header file using the list in [TechGeekBuzz: Best C++ Online Compiler](http://www.techgeekbuzz.com/best-cpp-online-compiler/?unapproved=1502&moderation-hash=34b4b15fca2dcd0d6f7c5b56149bb2ce#comment-1502)
 but they flag the error

> 1:21: fatal error: graphics.h: No such file or directory

The program I am trying to run is

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm, "C:\\tc\\bgi");
    circle(300,300,50);
    closegraph();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Because graphics.h is not a standard header file. AFAIK it's a Windows header file and most online IDEs use Linux so you will get the same problem with conio.h

Comment: Why would you expect `graphics.h` to be supported?

Comment: Because it has been obsolete for over 20 years.

Comment: It is an olden 16-bit real-mode DOS library, included with Borland's Turbo C and C++ products.  It worked by directly writing into the graphics adapter's memory, the kind of crime against humanity that was common in the early PC days before protected-mode operating systems became standard.  Emulator libraries have been written that work on a modern OS, the one provided by the University of Colorado is a top google hit.  Online compilers won't know anything about them.

Comment: @ThomasSablik -- it's not Windows. As mentioned in another comment, it comes from Borland's products, and was adapted by other compiler vendors at the time. Strictly DOS, as was conio.h.

Comment: There are a couple ports: https://github.com/SagarGaniga/Graphics-Library and https://github.com/rafiulgits/BGI-Projects/tree/master/Graphics%20in%20CodeBlocks for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only expect the standard headers to be available in online compilers.  Some  (but not all) also provide posix headers or very popular libraries such as boost.

Neither [`<graphics.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7860569/3723423) nor [`<conio.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792443/3723423) are standard headers. Both are old MSDOS legacy that you will not find on any online compiler:

- [`conio.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) offers non-standard and non-portable console functions, like for example the famous [`kbhit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29335796/3723423).
- [graphics.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Graphics_Interface) is a vendor specific header for a library that is no longer supported since 1997.

In addition, online compilers provide a command line interface.  They are not suitable for graphic development.