# dev-c++ and turbo c++ is not supported graphics .c

Tags: c++

In my computer my two ID  `Dev-c++` and `Turbo-c++` is not support `graphics.h` .I have no idea what going wrong.

Please give meany suggestion.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to use 25 year old compilers. The compilers where developed before the standard was made. What compiler do you use in Dev-C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)   This is the canonical for why trying to help you will be difficult.

Comment: You could replace Turbo C++ with a modern free version: [C++Builder Community Edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/starter)

Comment: This question should also answer your worries.  The two first hyperlinks are SO questions with relevant answers for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59704347/3723423