# Getting complilation and linking errors while trying to run a C code with ncurses

Tags: compilation, linker, ncurses

I want to implement a loop in C which stops when a particular key is pressed. For this I've been trying to use the ncurses library. I have a Redhat system which is offline and cannot be connected to the internet. Upon running the command `locate libncurses` I get a number of lines such as `/usr/lib64/libncurses++.so.5`. I assume this means that the ncurses library is present on my system. Next I try to run the following code to test ncurses

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int
main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    while (true) {
        if (getch() == 'g') {
            printw("You pressed G\n");
        }
        napms(500);
        printw("Running\n");
    }
}
```

This has been taken from the question [Using kbhit() and getch() on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335758/using-kbhit-and-getch-on-linux)

When I try to run this in the following manner `gcc -o testncurses testncurse.c` I get the error `undefined reference to 'initscr'`. Then I proceed to run it as `gcc -o testncurses testncurse.c -lncurses`. But I get the error

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses`

`collect2:error: ld returned 1 exit status`

What should I do so that the above code runs?

I have also tried installing a newer ncurses library package but that gives me an error saying that files in the package being installed conflicts with the already installed package.

Comment: Do you have the development package for ncurses installed?

Comment: As I said, while trying to install them I get the error that the package conflicts with already installed packages

Comment: You need the development package for ncurses. If you can't install it, you are probably out of luck. So, you should resolve the install conflict instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

first I recommend to run a hello world example to see if your library works properly:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{   
    initscr();          /* Start curses mode          */
    printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World          */
    refresh();          /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();            /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();           /* End curses mode        */

    return 0;
}
```

if it doesn't reinstall the library from the terminal but on the other hand try to run you code with this command  `gcc <program file> -lncurses`

without changing the name.
and try refresh() or wrefresh() after every printing

Comment: I get the same error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses`

`collect2:error: ld returned 1 exit status` on running your hello world program.